# Can I join gifs with different speed or delay?

Tags: python, imagemagick, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I tried to join two different gif with different delay, but the final output.gif has the same delay, not different... Is there a way to have different delays in one gif?

```
import subprocess
import os


def mk(i, o, delay=100):
    subprocess.call("convert -delay " +
                    delay + " -loop 5 " + i + " " + o, shell=True)


delay = input("Delay (default 100): ")
# mk("*png", "gif1, delay) # I used this to make the 2 gif
# with a delay of 100 and 30 respectively
# and then I joined them with the code below, but I dunno how to
# give them a separate delay... I want them one after the other
# in order of time
mk("*.gif", "output.gif", delay)
os.system("start output.gif")
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: may be because your `-delay` is same for all images or I didn't get you.

Comment: I used the code above to make gif number 1 at a certain delay (100) and the same code to make a number 2 gif with delay (30). To do this I used .png images. Then I changed to *.gif and I joined the two gifs together, but, obviously, they where both at 100... is there a way to join the gif1 (at 100 of delay) with the gif 2 (at 30 of delay), leaving the different delay in the same gif? ... I think the answer is not, but, who knows... I wish that the first part goes at 100 and when the second part starts it goes at 30.

Comment: looks like it possible, take a look on [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20666) thread

Comment: Why do you even specify the delay? Simply omit `-delay` and `convert` will do what you want

Comment: Please provide the 2 GIFs. What do you mean by *"combine"*? Play GIF1 then play GIF2 afterwards? Play GIF1 on the left side of the screen while GIF2 plays on the right side?

Comment: Here are my gifs... is there a way to join them (one after the other in order of time, not one and the other at the same time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The delay is a setting so it applies to all images following it, and remains set till you change it.

So let's make a red, green and blue image:

```
convert -size 400x250 xc:red  f1.gif
convert -size 400x250 xc:lime f2.gif
convert -size 400x250 xc:blue f3.gif
```

Now set the delay to 100 and animate the first three, then set it to 300 and animate the same three again but with the new delay this time:

```
convert -delay 100 f1.gif f2.gif f3.gif \
        -delay 300 f1.gif f2.gif f3.gif animated.gif
```

[image]

Now examine the delays associated with the various frames:

```
identify -format "%f[%s] %T\n" animated.gif
animated.gif[0] 100
animated.gif[1] 100
animated.gif[2] 100
animated.gif[3] 300
animated.gif[4] 300
animated.gif[5] 300
```

---

So I guess what you want is:

```
convert -delay 200 1.gif -coalesce \( -delay 30 2.gif -coalesce \) animated.gif
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it was just what I was looking for to give a different delay to that animation with the arrow that needs to go faster than the rest.